# Is it possible to set individual tint colors for each button on UITabBar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitabbar

Is it possible to have an individual tint color for a single `UITabBarItem` on the tab bar? I only know how to set it universally with `[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:`. But, for example, I want one tab to be tinted with blue when selected, the other one with red etc.

I know it can be partially mitigated by setting `image` and `selectedImage` properties with `UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal` to preserve the original image colors, but the caption text still has the original tint of the entire tab bar.

Comment: Please, check my detailed answer on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43002013/different-colors-for-tabbar-items-in-tab-bar-controller/47644313#47644313

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the tintColor property individual is impossible, but you can still change the text color for the tab bar item.

For example:

```
    [theTabBarItem setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor redColor]}
                                   forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [theTabBarItem setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor greenColor]}
                                   forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the individual tint color is not impossible, it just requires a fair bit of effort to achieve. The way to do it is to override the tab bar's `didSelectItem` method. When the user selects an item, you change the `tabBar.tintColor` to whatever `tintColor` you want for that item, and then have to call `selectedIndex = //The tapped index`. I'll post some code if you want, its certainly quite a hack

Answer (score 0):

Actually, with some tricks, you can set the tint of an individual button.

```
   let button1 = UITabBarItem(title: "Btn1", image: UIImage(systemName: "heart"), tag: 1)
   let button2 = UITabBarItem(title: "Btn2", image: UIImage(systemName: "heart"), tag: 2)
   let button3 = UITabBarItem(title: "Btn3", image: UIImage(systemName: "heart"), tag: 3)
   let button4 = UITabBarItem(title: "Btn4", image: UIImage(systemName: "heart"), tag: 4)
   let button5 = UITabBarItem(title: "Btn5", image: UIImage(systemName: "heart"), tag: 5)
   tabBar.items = [button1, button2, button3, button4, button5]

   // setting tint of the button4
   if let imageView = tabBar.subviews[4].subviews.first as? UIImageView {
      imageView.tintColor = UIColor.red 
      imageView.image = UIImage(systemName: "heart.fill")
   }
```

If you decide also to change the image of the button, use the same imageView and not button4.image, otherwise some other random button may change its tint. The tabBar.subviews[0] is the background image to the bar itself, the subsequent subviews are the buttons you added. Each element is of type UITabBarButton that has two subviews: first UITabBarSwappableImageView and the second UITabBarButtonLabel.

Answer (score -1):

**For Normal State (unselected):**

```
[tabBarItem setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor grayColor]}
                               forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

**For Selected State:**

```
[tabBarItem setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor blueColor]}
                               forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Comment: time waste - it changes the text color only